# Lumen - Routing with Prefix and Optional Parameter

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.4

I'm looking at routing in Lumen and it doesn't appear to be working correctly and I can't work out if it's an issue or my understanding.

```
$router->get('{adaptor}[/{id}]',     ['uses' => 'MyController@readAction']);
```

This way works, but I'd prefer to use a prefix to group all my routes:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => '{adaptor}'], function () use ($router) {
        $router->get('[/{id}]',      ['uses' => 'MyController@readAction']);
       // CRUD routes to be added here
});
```

If I go to `/acme` I get MethodNotAllowed Exception, but if I add `/acme/1` it works fine. Does a prefix NEED another route item for it to work?

Answer (score 3):

A prefix will need another route item in order for it to work correctly.

https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters

> Optional parameters are only supported in a trailing position of the URI.

Comment: Not sure it's classed as that, as it is technically trailing now.